# How can We convert raw query to laravel query

Tags: mysql, laravel, subquery, left-join, laravel-query-builder

I created a SQL script with subquery and join. I need to convert this raw query in laravel.

Raw query is :

```
select users.name, users.user_type,
count(complaints.id) as total_case, 
sum(if(complaints.action = 'Resolved', 1, 0)) as total_resolved_case, 
sum(if(complaints.action = 'Pending', 1, 0)) as total_pending_case, 
sum(if(complaints.action = 'Unrelated', 1, 0)) as total_unrelated_case, 
sum(if(complaints.action = 'Rejected', 1, 0)) as total_rejected_case,
sum(if((complaints.sla_timeline < '2021-07-22 09:40:58' AND complaints.action = 'Pending'), 1, 0)) as total_overdue_case 
from complaint_history
left join complaints on complaint_history.complaint_id = complaints.id
left join users on complaint_history.action_by = users.id
where users.department_id = (
     select users.department_id 
     from complaint_history 
     left join users on complaint_history.assigned_to = users.id 
     LIMIT 1
) 
and complaint_history.created_at is not null
group by users.name
```

Please help me. thank you!

Comment: What did you try already?  SO is not made for pure code writing requests. In this case you will have to search for a free lancer etc. to do your job.

Comment: why would you translate it if it works by using raw sql ? $data = DB::select('select xxxx', []);

Answer (score 0):

try to using DB::select(); from laravel

and from what you ask, you can just try code like it

```
$query = DB::select("select users.name, users.user_type,
     count(complaints.id) as total_case, 
     sum(if(complaints.action = 'Resolved', 1, 0)) as total_resolved_case, 
     sum(if(complaints.action = 'Pending', 1, 0)) as total_pending_case, 
     sum(if(complaints.action = 'Unrelated', 1, 0)) as total_unrelated_case, 
     sum(if(complaints.action = 'Rejected', 1, 0)) as total_rejected_case,
     sum(if((complaints.sla_timeline < '2021-07-22 09:40:58' AND complaints.action = 'Pending'), 1, 0)) as total_overdue_case 
     from complaint_history
     left join complaints on complaint_history.complaint_id = complaints.id
     left join users on complaint_history.action_by = users.id
     where users.department_id = (
         select users.department_id 
         from complaint_history 
         left join users on complaint_history.assigned_to = users.id 
         LIMIT 1
     ) 
     and complaint_history.created_at is not null
     group by users.name
")
```